# Cannot port install Ruby

Tags: ruby, macports, osx-mavericks

I am having trouble installing ruby through mac ports. The error that I am receiving is this one:

```
:error:extract org.macports.extract for port ruby returned: command execution failed
:debug:extract Error code: NONE
:debug:extract Backtrace: command execution failed
while executing
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:extract Warning: targets not executed for ruby: org.macports.activate
```

Can anyone help with this error? So far I have tried doing:

```
port -v selfupdate
xcodebuild -license agree
```

Neither of those seemed to fix my target issue.

Anyone have other tips?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using MacPorts instead of using RVM to install ruby? Also, I would recommend using HomeBrew instead of MacPorts generally (though, using RVM for installing Ruby versions is the way I would go -- use homebrew for other things).

Comment: I just have macports installed and am familiar with using it. What is the advantage of RVM over macports?

Comment: Also, I fixed my error. Turns out with each OS update you actually need to go to the MacPorts webpage and download the new version. Doing a selfupdate does not do that like I thought it would.

Comment: Good to hear it's sorted - didn't know that about MacPorts. I recommend RVM for managing Ruby versions and Home Brew for various other things for the same reason - they're what I'm comfortable with. They have also been reliable and they seem to be more widely used throughout the community.

You should write up what you did to fix it as an answer and then accept it later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem what I had to do was go to the MacPorts webpage, download the new Mavericks MacPorts package, and run through that installation. I thought that doing a port -v selfupdate would update my current MacPorts to the Mavericks OS MacPorts but unfortunately it did not.

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced using `macports`, and would rather prefer [homebrew](http://brew.sh) over it, at the moment.

However, to install Ruby (or specific versions of Ruby), I would really recommend using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io).

It seems that you are new to ruby, and if that is the case, I would further advice you to use `rbenv` over `RVM`. You will find it more pleasant, at the moment. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Why use homebrew or rbenv over macports? I fixed my error, turns out you need to redownload macports with every OS update. port -v selfinstall didn't actuall update it to my current OS like I thought the command would.

Comment: This should answer your question: http://chadthompson.me/2013/05/06/why-homebrew/  
I did a google query, and preferred someone else to give his views over this topic rather than my own, a.k.a. third party intervention :)